# Workaround for inlined SQL function dispatch in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

## Goal

I'm trying to make PostgreSQL do something like function dispatch, but I'm open to any other solution for the problem that lets me keep the function I'm calling a SQL function (versus PL/PGSQL) because I want it to be inlined.

Suppose I have two functions like:

```sql
create or replace function is_in_view_one(p people) returns boolean as $$
  select p.state = ANY(ARRAY['TX', 'NY', 'CA'])
$$ language sql strict stable;
```

And:

```sql
create or replace function is_in_view_two(p people) returns boolean as $$
  select p.state = ANY(ARRAY['NV', 'FL', 'MT'])
$$ language sql strict stable;
```

I want to be able to write some code, or adapt the above functions, so I can write:

```sql
select count(*)
from people
where is_in_view(people, 'one');
```

And I want `is_in_view` to be fully inline-able according to these criteria: [https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions'](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions%27)

## Attempted Solution via Domains

I've tried to set up a solution using domains as function identifiers, and although it doesn't work, I think someone more knowledgeable about PostgreSQL types, casts, and function identification might know how to hack it.

I tried to do:

```sql
create domain view_one_id as uuid check (value = 'ed744964-6561-11eb-878e-c7ad77d3260a');
create domain view_two_id as uuid check (value = 'fa9fe0f8-6561-11eb-878e-c79c81b46d0c');

create or replace function say_n(v view_one_id) returns integer as $$
  select 1 
$$ language sql strict;

create or replace function say_n(v view_two_id) returns integer as $$
  select 2 
$$ language sql strict;
```

Hoping that I could then do:

```sql
select say_n('ed744964-6561-11eb-878e-c7ad77d3260a') # 1
select say_n('fa9fe0f8-6561-11eb-878e-c79c81b46d0c') # 2
```

But instead I get:

```sql
=# select say_n('fa9fe0f8-6561-11eb-878e-c79c81b46d0c');
ERROR:  function say_n(unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: select say_n('fa9fe0f8-6561-11eb-878e-c79c81b46d0c');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I can do:

```sql
=# select say_n('fa9fe0f8-6561-11eb-878e-c79c81b46d0c'::view_two_id);
 say_n 
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

But in order to integrate with external tooling that knows how to call functions and only call functions (not also supply a variable type cast) I'm holding out hope for a solution that doesn't require modifications to this external tooling.

Happy to entertain alternatives! I feel like this solution might be possible by fiddling with the `CAST` or something, however.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `CASE`:

```
select p.state = ANY (CASE WHEN $2 = 'one'
                           THEN ARRAY['TX', 'NY', 'CA']
                           ELSE ARRAY['NV', 'FL', 'MT']
                      END)
```

But if you want efficiency, you would be better off with the two functions, because the above cannot use an index.